# Android: Facebook Group Posting

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

So basically, I have a Post To Group button in my application which enables users to Post something to **A Specific Group** which I have provided ID of.

I have the required Permission for "publish_to_groups" which is step one for this.

I am using the following code for posting:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", "This is a test message");/ make the API call /new 
GraphRequest(    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
"/MY_GROUP_ID_HERE/feed",    
params,   
HttpMethod.POST,    new GraphRequest.Callback() {        
public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {     
     // I GET NULL HERE
     }    
}).executeAsync();
```

What am I missing here? I have followed developer.facebook for this but still I am not able to get the results. There is very limited info regarding Group Posts.

Can someone provide some direction to this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try the request with the same parameters and access token in Graph API Explorer, and see what you get there.

Comment: I have to post in a group so how can i test for post?

Comment: In GAE you mean? Select POST in the select field that currently shows GET, and then add the needed parameters.

Comment: Yes I have selected the post but my requirement is not getting the user info as I have to post a message for example "test message" in that group.So what are the parameters or query used to post the message.

Comment: Who said anything about getting user info? I said you should make the same request you are currently trying to make from your coding, with the same parameters and the same values.

Comment: I am doing like this image URL : https://imgur.com/a/7QikKUw
and getting success message but nothing to post in the target group.

Comment: I said you should test the *same* request in there, not something completely different … Why are you making a request to `/me`, when in your code it was `/MY_GROUP_ID_HERE/feed` …?

Comment: By making the request like /XXXXX/feed
I am getting the 

"error": {
    "message": "Unsupported post request. Object with ID 'XXXXX' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 33,
    "fbtrace_id": "XXXXXXXEXFNe8"
  }

Comment: That permission publish_to_groups is only one of the requirements. Your app must also be “installed” in the group, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/groups-api#app-installation Plus, you will need to get your app reviewed to use this feature, before it will work when the app is in live mode, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/groups-api#app-review

Comment: I am not aware of how to add publish_to_groups permission. Remaining is done as expected like app is added in the group and review is done by facebook.
How can I add this permission in the code?

Comment: Permissions are asked for during login. Go read the documentation for specifics.

Comment: I am using read permission at the time of login and as per doc publish permission can not be used with read permission. That's why I am not able to add this permission in my code.

After searching on google I have added this code
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(mActivity,Arrays.asList("publish_to_groups"));

But the app still does not have the permission.

Comment: But your app is still in dev mode, and you are trying this with a user that has a role in your app, yes?

Comment: No, My app is in prod mode which has facebook login functionality. The user login with facebook want to post in a group and the app is already added in that group.

Comment: Well did you get this permission reviewed already? Otherwise, you can not ask for it in live mode.

Comment: Yes my app has been go through with the review and has the required permission provided by facebook.

Comment: Well then you must have successfully been able to ask for this permission before in your app … otherwise you would not have been able to get this through review in the first place.